# Simple DNA pattern matching

Tags: python, string

I have a simple code for finding multiple pattern matching from a certain text (specifically for DNA sequence pattern matching)

```
text = "CTGATTCC"
pattern = "ATT", "CT", "TTT"
set = []
for x in pattern:
    for i in range(0, len(text)-len(x)+1):
        if text[i:(i+len(x))] == x:
            set.append(i+1)
print("Positions:", set)
```

The code is already set, but I want to try if I can make the code print `"Pattern is not found"` for pattern that can't be found in the text. I can't figure out where to put it inside the loop. Any ideas would really help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary list for each pattern, then verifying whether or not you found it

```
values = []
for x in pattern:
    sub_values = []
    for i in range(0, len(text) - len(x) + 1):
        if text[i:i + len(x)] == x:
            sub_values.append((x, i + 1))
    if sub_values:
        values.extend(sub_values)
    else:
        print("Pattern", x, "not found")
```

```
Pattern TTT not found
Positions: [('ATT', 4), ('CT', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use a regex approach here.  We can form an alternation of all base pair sequences you want to find.  Then use `re.findall` to find all matches.  Whatever patterns were *not* matched can then be obtained using set arithmetic.

```py
text = "CTGATTCC"
patterns = ["ATT", "CT", "TTT"]
regex = r'(' + r'|'.join(patterns) + r')'
matches = re.findall(regex, text)
misses = set(patterns) - set(matches)
print(misses)  # set(['TTT'])
```

Comment: this is the first time i heard of this module. thank you, will check it out!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
text = "CTGATTCC"
pattern = "ATT", "CT", "TTT"
set = []
match = False

for x in pattern:
    if match: match = False

    for i in range(0, len(text)-len(x)+1):
        if text[i:(i+len(x))] == x:
            set.append(i+1)
            if not match: match = True

    if not match:
        print(f"Pattern not found: {x}")

set = set if len(set) > 0 else "None"
print("Positions: ", set)
```

This will also output

```
Positions: None
```

if nothing is appended to set.

Answer (score 0):

After the second loop, if the array "set" doesn't increase it means that "x" pattern wasn't found.

```
text = "CTGATTCC"
pattern = "ATT", "CT", "TTT"
set = []
for x in pattern:
    sLen = len(set)
    for i in range(0, len(text)-len(x)+1):
        if text[i:(i+len(x))] == x:
            set.append(i+1)
    if len(set) == sLen:
        print("Not Found: ", x)
print("Positions:", set)
```

Your code anyway got bugs because of the following scenarios:

1. The pattern is bigger than the text
2. The text or pattern is empty